# Verify level of SSL/TLS used on a .NET socket?

Tags: .net, sockets, ssl

Given a connected socket (or TCPClient) in .NET, how can I find out within my application, which level of SSL/TLS is being used? For example: SSL 2, SSL 3, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2.

For example, some API calls that give me the equivalent of socket.getSSLLevel()

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can maybe use [SslStream.SslProtocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.sslprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx)
but it's not clear whether that gives the actual protocol in use or just the one I asked for when I called AuthenticateAsClient